# Jquery css animation is not smooth in ipad safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Smooth animation is not occuring in ipad safari with jquery animate

```
$('#myId').css({ 'left': '-100%' }).animate({ 'left': '0' }, 300, 'linear');
```

I tried it with add class option too,
Provided css transition in that class
transition: left 2s ease;

Is there any way to give smooth animation using jquery or css to work as same as in google chrome.

I admit there will be some factors including hardware performance and network speed.

Comment: Use CSS instead of JS for animations. It's hardware accelerated and performs much better - even on an iPad.

Comment: tried it with css transition but it is also showing as same as jquery animate

Comment: In which case please share all relevant code so we can help you debug this.

Comment: $('#myId').css({ 'left': '-100%' }).animate({ 'left': '0' }, 300, 'linear'); this is the jquery code i used to animate the div 
Below is used as an alternate option $('#myId').addClass('animate');
#myId{
transition: left 2s ease;
}

Comment: What about the HTML and all the other relevant CSS on the layout to recreate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to use css transition. The transition animation could be like this:

```css
#myId {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  display:block;
}

#myId:hover {
  transition: left 3s linear;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myId"></div>
```

To learn more about css transitions please visit https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp for example. :)

Regards

Comment: Already done it my friend but the css transition is also not smooth in ipad, i think it may be the device performance/network may be the issue

Comment: You can use chrome developer tools for a counter testing. Limit your network speed in the developer tools to see if it affetcs the transition. It should not be the case! The hardware accelarance should also not be significant due to the simplicity of the animation. It should run smooth but try it with dev tools. :) You find them by pressing F12 in your browser. The option can be found under "Network conditions" Tab. :)

Comment: Also, does my example run smooth for you? Or does it lag also. Can you try it aswell?

Comment: I'm not talking about the ipad emulator, it is an actual device. So the network speed can't be adjusted :)

Answer (score 0):

The `left` property does not use hardware acceleration when animated, so it will be janky regardless of whether it is in your stylesheet or applied with JS.

You would be better off using `translateX()` inside a `transform`, which does use hardware acceleration to execute the animation.

```
transform: translateX(-100%);
```